# Steam:// link not "unsafe"

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-3, steam

I'm trying to get Steam's add friends' link to work but for some reason my sanitation isn't working.  I'm very new to angular (first app) and so I may be missing something huge/obvious.  This is the code I added to my config and my html.  I'm using angular 1.1.5.  The link to steam below displays as "unsafe" and does not function.  The sanitation doesn't seem to be working as intended.

Thanks in advance!

```
@app.config(['$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) ->
   $routeProvider.
  when('/casters', {
    templateUrl: '../templates/casters/index.html',
        controller: 'CasterIndexCtrl'
      }).
    otherwise({
      templateUrl: '../templates/home.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    }) 
], 
['$compileProvider', ($compileProvider) ->
$compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|steam|mailto|file):/);
])

<tr ng-repeat="caster in casters">
    <td><a ng-href="steam://friends/add/{{caster.steam_id}}"><button type="button" class="butn btn-link">Add</button></a></td>
    <td>{{caster.name}}</td>
    <td><a href="http://twitch.tv/{{caster.twitch}}" target="_blank">{{caster.twitch}}</a></td>
    <td>Column content</td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an href sanitization:

```
$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|tel|file|steam):/);
```

This is basically appending `steam` to the regex [in santizeUri.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/47ab8df455df1f1391b760e1fbcc5c21645512b8/src/ng/sanitizeUri.js#L7)

I *believe* `urlSanitizationWhitelist` was changed in version 1.2? I remember having a similar issue getting this to work based on blogs and just dug around in the source until I found the answer. At the time I had the same problem, angular's docs were down, but it looks like [they have been updated](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/%24sanitize) with this information.

Also, be sure that you're including `ngSanitize` both as a dependency and referencing the `angular-sanitize.js` file.

edit: oh I missed you're on 1.1.5. I'll see if I can track it down in that revision.

edit 2: So I created [a plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/4k0uNbVgUO4AzWChI2uZ?p=preview) with just the compile override to allow steam, and this works to launch steam.

Then, I noticed you're passing two config functions to `.config` (I think, I don't read coffeescript).

Try this:

```
@app.config(['$routeProvider','$compileProvider', ($routeProvider, $compileProvider) ->
   $routeProvider.
  when('/casters', {
    templateUrl: '../templates/casters/index.html',
        controller: 'CasterIndexCtrl'
      }).
    otherwise({
      templateUrl: '../templates/home.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    }) 

    $compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|steam|mailto|file):/);
])
```

http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/angular.Module

The docs for angular 1.1.5 are pretty terrible. They don't really clearly explain the whole array injector thing. This `configFn` is either a single function or an array of dependencies that are to be injected into the function (last array element).

Comment: Yeah, I had found aHrefSanitizationWhitelist but it said that it was for a later version.  I thought urlSanitizationWhitelist but maybe (hopefully) I'm mistaken.  I'd love for that to be the problem.

Comment: I updated my answer. Looks like it may be a formatting issue that got you with the multiple arrays for the `configFn` parameter.

Comment: You nailed it.  I was passing the functions in wrong.  I was just kind of guessing how they should be passed in since I couldn't find a good example of where I'm doing multiple config deals.  Thanks!!

Comment: No problem. If you don't necessarily need to stay on 1.1.5, I'd recommend going up to 1.2.x. My team had a hell of a time trying to *figure out* things on 1.1.5 and the documentation for 1.2.2 (which we're on right now) has proven way more helpful. Although, 1.3.x docs look pretty full in comparison.